# sum of particular items of N lists using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I have a task to analyse N texts using NLTK. Each text is longer than 100k words, so it is hard for computer to process so many data and that's why I decided to split each text after tokenizing in sublists like this:

`chunks = [tokens_words[x:x+1000] for x in range (0,len(tokens_words), 1000)]`

Probably, it works well.

And then I need to count, for example, number of nouns in each text. I do it like this:

```
for chunk in chunks:
    for key in tagged.keys():
        for noun_tag in noun_tags:
            if tagged[key] == noun_tag:
                noun += 1
    totalNoun.append(noun)
```

then I use `sum()` and find percentage. I also tried `totalNoun += noun` but in both ways I receive smth like 3500% or 2498%.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: More detail is required. What are you using `sum()` on? How are you finding the percentage? This seems like an arithmetic error more than a Python one but there's not really any way to be sure without more detail.

Comment: A wild guess would be that you are using the **percentage format** (something like `{:.2%}`) for your `print()` or `write()` but still multiplying by 100 when doing the calculation. So, remove the 100*.

Comment: Do you get the correct noun count for one chunk?

Comment: I use NLTK's `pos_tag`. It helps me to find all nouns and it worked correctly before I tried to improve my code because everything was right when I worked with small text files and I received smth weird when I worked with large files (like there was only 4% of nouns in text with 80k words and so on).

Comment: And I don't use the percentage format. Just nouns number / words number *100

Comment: The weird thing is that "chunk" is not used anywhere.  Are you sure the subcounts are the noun count for that particular chunk? That's my question. Or could you be counting all the nouns each time you think you are counting the nouns in one chunk.

Comment: Kenny Ostrom, I'm not sure. `print(noun)` without `totalNoun` and `sum()` doesn't work better, numbers are still too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have 2 chunks, one with 13 nouns and one with 30 nouns. Your code will do the following:

```
noun: 0
totalNoun: []

# processing chunk 1 with 13 nouns...

noun : 13
totalNoun : [13]

# processing chunk 2 with 30 nouns...

noun : 43
totalNoun : [13,43]
```

As far as I can see, you do not set `noun` equal to 0 after each chunk. That is:

```
for chunk in chunks:
    ## HERE ##
    noun = 0
    ## HERE ##

    for key in tagged.keys():
        for noun_tag in noun_tags:
            if tagged[key] == noun_tag:
                noun += 1
    totalNoun.append(noun)
```

Using `noun = 0` in your `for chunk in chunks` loop should do the trick.

Comment: It helped, thank you! For some reason I placed `noun=0` before all chunks and forgot about it.